# High volume battery for MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, hardware-recommendation

Can you advise me of where or if it a high capacity battery exists to replace my pre unibody battery on a MacBook Pro?

Comment: not an answer but more of an advisory: Supposedly the NuPower batteries they sell at [OWC][1] are higher capacity, but I found with my PowerBook G4 that they weren't all they claim to be.  The battery was down to 90% capacity within about a week...


  [1]: http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/apple_laptop/batteries/MacBook_Pro_17

Answer (score 1):

A quick search turned up [Fastmac replacement batteries](http://fastmac.com/laptop.php) which claim to

> ...replace the computer’s original battery with a larger capacity and longer lasting advanced power cell battery that utilizes TruePower technology. With up to 68% more capacity...

Comment: Thanks, I know about it but I suppose to get answers based on personal experience.